# Is every non-simple finite group constructible from simple groups of lesser order by extensions?

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, group-extensions

The question is easy to formulate:
Let be $G$ a finite group with some normal subgroup, let's say $N \triangleleft G$ where $N\neq \{1\}$ and $N\neq G$. The question is, there exists an group homomorphism $\alpha : N\hookrightarrow G$ and other group homomorfism $\beta : G \twoheadrightarrow G/N$ such $im \; \alpha \; = \; ker\; \beta$?
As in the commentaries say me, it's trivial $\alpha\equiv Id_N$ and $\beta\equiv \pi: G \rightarrow G/N :: x \mapsto xN$, is a first immediate answer.
Then, the question is, can every non-simple finite group be constructible from simple groups of lesser order by extensions?

Comment: Take $\alpha(x)=x$ the standard inclusion and $\beta(x)=xN$ the standard projection? Being solvable, finite or any other property doesn't matter.

Comment: Thanks, I've just seen that the question was trivial.